# Do I need to have all the go dependency packages in place on production server

Tags: go

I am deploying my new Golang web application to production, and I have built the executable binary, when I upload the binary to production, do I also need to have all the go depenecy packages on production too ?

For example, I am using `github.com/jinzhu/gorm`, do I need to copy `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` to production too?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to deploy these. They are already compiled inside your binary.